# Integrating Paypal with .Net Core 3

Tags: .net-core, paypal, .net-core-3.1

I have a .Net Core 3 project and I want to integrate Paypal.

In past projects I was using `Paypal` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal/2.0.0-rc2), but now I was reading their [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/)  and they recommend to use version 2 of their API. (*Previously I was using version 1 with `Paypal` SDK*). If I go to the nuget.com and check the `Paypal` package I see that version 2 of this package is still `rc`:

```
Version     Downloads   Last updated        
2.0.0-rc2   143,570     2018-04-12T18:17:40Z
```

Now it has been almost 2 years in this, so it doesn't look promising. If I check their docs again I find that they recommend using following package: [`PayPalCheckoutSdk`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalCheckoutSdk/). Link to their [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/). If I try to copy-paste an exampe it doesn't even compile (*mainly due to some properties renamed*). This really doesn't give a lot of confidence in using this package at all. My last resort would be just to call paypal API directly without using their provided SDK.

What is the best way to integrate paypal with my server running on .Net Core 3.1?

Options:

- Use `paypal 2.0.0-rc2`
- Use `PayPalCheckoutSdk`
- Call API directly

Comment: I'ts a REST API, so you *don't* really need an SDK. Besides, the quality of the SDKs provided by all payment providers is .... well, they aren't selling software, are they? The "SDKs" are typically classes generated from their schemas with some questionable boilerplate code. Sometimes, the boilerplate comes from migrating Java code to .NET. For example, by now everyone should know that HttpClient should be reused and yet, [the Paypal SDK creates a new instance for each call](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK/issues/33). This can be very bad for big e-Commerce sites (guess how I know)

Comment: You can borrow the DTOs from the SDK's code adn use them with your own code. This will save you a lot of boring work. You can study their code to see how authentication works. Make sure you avoid "undortunate" ideas like [using injectors](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK/blob/develop/PayPalCheckoutSdk/Core/PaypalHttpClient.cs) to add the `Gzip` header, something easily done by simply setting a DefaultHeader! Same for the Authorization Injector. The `PayPalHttpClient` doesn't really offer anything over a simple HttpClient or Factory config

Comment: After looking at the SDK, it's just DTOs and an overcomplicated HttpClient. The examples are for *Java's* HttpClient class - .NET's HttpClient doesn't have an `exectue` method`.

Comment: Thanks for response. The SDK seems really poor. I went with the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call the v2/orders API directly.

Server-side create: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create

Server-side capture: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture

Follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for the 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code'). Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server